# Access to string as input and output in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

I'm new to OpenModelica. Can anybody guide me if it is possible to pass a string or character array as input to an OpenModelica model and get output as a string using the same?

I've tried to define a string as a parameter, and it is working, but I can't access this outside the FMU model.